# Remaking std::to_string in C++ with UDLs (User Defined Literals)

Tags: c++, strings, c++11

I would like some feedback on what I should change with my semi remake of `std::to_string` with UDLs (user-defined literals).

This is compiled and working on linux with C++11 using `g++`.

```
#include <deque> // if you use vectors instead you have to add them to the 
//string in reverse order (no push_front())
#include <string>

std::string operator"" _str(unsigned long long int num)
{
  std::deque<char> digits;
  for(char i = 0; num != 0;num = num / 10)
  {
      i = '0'+(num % 10);
      digits.push_front(i);
  }
  std::string converternum;
  for(auto i = 0; i< digits.size();i++)
    converternum += digits[i];
  return converternum;
}

char * operator"" _cstr(unsigned long long int num)
{
   std::deque<char> digits;
   for(char i = 0; num != 0;num = num / 10)
   {
     i = '0'+(num % 10);
     digits.push_front(i);
   }
   std::string converternum;
   for(auto i = 0; i< digits.size();i++)
   converternum += digits[i];
   char * string = (char *)converternum.c_str();
   return string;//converternum.c_str();
}
```

Comment: I see a few close votes, but I think this question is fine. I hope you get some good answers!

Comment: If you are working with literals, why not just type `auto cstr = "213";`instead of `auto cstr = 213_cstr;`? You save yourself from having to include this library, the 3 characters typed per use, and having to manage the lifetime of the C string.  I'm not really seeing the benefit for either C strings or C++ strings.

Comment: @Snowhawk : A decidedly contrived answer to your question:  one could use `operator ""_str(std::numeric_limits<long long>::digits10)` to get a numeric value in string form.

Comment: @Edward That doesn't look like valid C++, but if you wanted the simplest way to stringify an integer literal, you could simply do `auto operator ""_str(char const* s) { return std::string{s}; }` - that is, take a `char const*` parameter rather than `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 7):

I'm ignoring all the testing stuff, and just focusing on the two conversion functions.

```
std::string operator"" _str(unsigned long long int num)
{
    std::deque<char> digits;
```

There's really no need for the deque. You can `push_back()` all the digits directly into a `std::string`, and then use `std::reverse()`.

To make it even better, you could use the max value of an `unsigned long long` and calculate the maximum number of digits you'll need, then use `reserve()`. But that probably won't net you any real gains in reality, since you'll likely always be under the small-string optimization size where `std::string` won't actually allocate any memory... another reason to ditch the deque and stick with strings.

```
for(char i = 0; num != 0;num = num / 10)
```

Have you tested your conversion functions with zero? Because if `num` is zero, this loop won't fire at all, and `digits` will be empty. So `"0"_str` will result in `""`.

This is a pretty weird and confusing loop in general. `i` *looks* like it's going to be some kind of loop counter, but it's not. All-in-all, this just looks like a case of trying to be too clever, and outsmarting yourself (due to the zero issue).

This could be expressed much more simply and clearly as something like:

```
do
{
    digits.push_front('0' + (num % 10));
    num /= 10;
} while (num != 0);
```

and it won't have the zero bug. (`do` loops are less common than `while`, but the reason to use one here - and this should be documented in a comment - is to guarantee that even if `num` is zero, the loop will fire at least once.)

{snipped section about digit character codes}

```
std::string converternum;
```

I already mentioned that the deque is unnecessary, but if you're really going to use it, you should take advantage of the fact that you know `digits.size()`, and use `reserve()` for this string to prevent unnecessary allocations.

```
char * operator"" _cstr(unsigned long long int num)
```

This function is mostly identical to the first one, and thus has the same problems. Again, I would ditch the deque and just work with a string. The digits will be in reverse order, but in this case you can fix that with `std::reverse_copy()` when you copy them into your output buffer.

```
char * string = (char *)converternum.c_str();
return string;//converternum.c_str();
```

Here is where you get into *real* trouble.

First, never, ever use C-style casts. In this case, you've cast away the constness of `c_str()`... that's bad. Prior to C++17, if you want a non-`const` pointer to `std::string`'s data, you have to jump through some hoops - you have to do something like `&convertnum[0]` or `&convertnum.front()` - and I agree that's a pain. But casting away constness is a red flag that won't pass most code reviews, because it is *extremely* dangerous.

Second, you are taking a pointer to `convertnum`'s internal data, and returning that... even though `convertnum` is being destroyed. In other words, you are returning a pointer to freed memory, which is UB.

How do you solve these problems? Well, the don't answer is: Don't use C-style strings. In other words, don't have a `_cstr` UDL. It's only going to give you grief (it already has!).

But if you really, really *must*... one option is to do what @hoffmale suggests, and instead of `char*`, return `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`. That might look something like this:

```
char* operator"" _cstr(unsigned long long int num)
{
    auto digits = std::string{};
    do
    {
        digits += '0' + (num % 10);
        num /= 10;
    } while (num != 0);

    auto p = std::make_unique<char[]>(digits.size() + 1);

    std::reverse_copy(digits.cbegin(), digits.cend(), p.get());
    p[digits.size()] = '\0'; // have to manually add the null terminator

    return p;
}
```

The problem with that is you're now longer returning a C-string, which makes "`_cstr`" kind of a lie.

So another option is to have some kind of storage with a lifetime longer than the function that will retain the memory for you. Something like:

```
char* operator"" _cstr(unsigned long long int num)
{
    // Note: you *can't* use a vector<string>, because string's
    // memory may be invalidated on moves, like if the vector
    // resizes.
    static auto storage = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<char[]>>{};

    auto digits = std::string{};
    do
    {
        digits += '0' + (num % 10);
        num /= 10;
    } while (num != 0);

    auto p = std::make_unique<char[]>(digits.size() + 1);

    std::reverse_copy(digits.cbegin(), digits.cend(), p.get());
    p[digits.size()] = '\0';

    // Get the char*, and then move the unique_ptr into storage
    // to let it be managed there.
    auto result = p.get();
    storage.push_back(std::move(p));

    return result;
}
```

This will "work", and it's basically what some C libraries do (when they don't simply leak). But with no way to release the memory, it will just grow and grow. You *could* add a mechanism to release the memory, but you would need a way to be sure it's safe for every string. This solution is possible, but unwieldy.

The last solution - the worst case (other than outright UB) - is to define some sort of contract that client code must follow. In plain English, document the function by saying "you must `delete[]` the memory when you're done with it". That requires programmers to behave, and is very easy to break, so it is *not* recommended. But... if you *really* want a C-string function, it's an option. A bad one, but an option nonetheless.

## Summary

You have one critical error in your code:

- In `""_cstr(unsigned long long)`, you return a pointer to the internal memory of a `std::string` that gets destroyed at the end of the function, meaning you're returning a pointer to invalid memory.

You have a couple of logical errors in your code:

- Both functions will return an empty string when the number is zero, instead of `"0"`.

You have a few inefficiencies:

- You use deques because you want to add the numbers in reverse order, and reason that makes sense because neither strings nor vectors have `push_front()`. But that's all unnecessary. You can simply `push_back()` directly into your result string, and then use `std::reverse()`. (Or `push_back()` into a string buffer, and `std::reverse_copy()` into your final buffer.)

And here are some tips to keep in mind:

It's really good that you're doing testing, but if you're going to do that, you might as well go all in and use something like Google Test. It's header-only, a single include, and it produces very pretty output. A full battery of tests can give you great confidence in your code. Using Google Test might look something like (fair warning, I don't actually use Google Test that often):

```
TEST(StrTest, HandlesZero) {
    EXPECT_EQ(0_str, "0");
}
```

To test that the types are right, rather than trying to demangle the names (which, by the way, it's been a long time since I've used `abi::__cxa_demangle()`, but I'm pretty sure you're not using it correctly), it's so much easier to just use type traits:

```
TEST(StrTest, ReturnType) {
    EXPECT_TRUE((std::is_same_v<decltype(0_str), std::string>));
}
```

Another dirty trick you can use to examine types is deliberately generating errors:

```
template <typename T>
struct TD; // note, never define TD

TD<decltype(0_str)> t; // will trigger an error
```

The error generated will print the *exact* type of whatever is in the angle brackets, on every compiler. This is a hackish way to check types, but it can help when you're experimenting.

Comment: C++ guarantees that digits are contiguous. [lex.charset]/3: "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous."

Comment: That's good to know. I'm battle-scarred after EBCDIC and its non-contiguous letters.

Comment: I certainly can't blame you for that!

Comment: For tests of type equality, I prefer to do that at compile-time - e.g. `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(0_str), std::string>);`

Comment: In case it's not obvious - the `static_assert` can still be in the test method.  Example in a recent question of mine: [Compute mean and variance, incrementally](/q/198124).

Comment: @TobySpeight Static asserts are good for *constraining* parameter/input types. But there are a lot of good reasons to prefer using a test framework for *testing* created/output types. For example: while a static assert will kill a build in its tracks, tests doesn't prevent other tests from running (unless you specify they should)... meaning you get much more information out a single run (through your CI or whatever). That can be important for turnaround time and productivity.

Comment: @TobySpeight Another really good reason to prefer using the testing framework is that static asserts only generate information when they fail - if your build succeeds, you don't know if an assertion passed or if it was never run at all. This can be especially problematic for dependant template types, because it's hard to be sure you tried to instantiate everything you wanted to test. All testing frameworks can produce feedback for even successful tests, so you *know* you tested everything you wanted to test.

Comment: @TobySpeight I'm a big fan of doing as much at compile time as possible, but the compiler is *NOT* a testing framework.

Comment: In that case, I'd love you to go over to the question I linked and give your suggestions on how to improve that aspect of it.  I might not agree with you, but I would appreciate see your reasoning laid out, along with your preferred version.

Comment: @TobySpeight I'm not really all that comfortable with Google Test - it's not a test framework I think much of - so the only comments I'd be able to make would be the generic advice you'd get from any testing guide: keep tests simple, test one thing at a time, use value/type parameterized tests (would save a *lot* of repetition in those tests!), and so on. It wouldn't really be much help.

Answer (score 5):

> Note: Intermingling actual implementation code and testing code/usage example makes for bad reading.

`std::string` has a constructor that takes two iterators and constructs its contents from them. This allows `_str` to be simplified to:

```
std::string operator"" _str(unsigned long long int num)
{
    std::deque<char> digits;

    for(; num != 0; num /= 10)
    {
        auto digit = '0' + (num % 10);
        digits.push_front(digit);
    }

    return std::string{ std::begin(digits), std::end(digits) };
}
```

Similar applies to `_cstr`. But beware! Since `converternum` in `_cstr` gets destructed once the function returns, the pointer returned by `c_str()` earlier will dangle. To return a valid `char*`, a copy has to be made - and in that case, the memory could be managed directly anyways:

```
char* operator"" _cstr(unsigned long long int num)
{
    std::deque<char> digits;

    for(; num != 0; num /= 10)
    {
        char digit = char{'0'+(num % 10)};
        digits.push_front(digit);
    }

    auto string = new char[digits.size() + 1];

    std::copy(std::begin(digits), std::end(digits), string);
    string[digits.size()] = '\0';

    return string;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to learn more about the standard lib algorithms for these classes and appreciate your help in doing so

Comment: @Mememyselfandaverycreepy: Generally, I'd suggest returning a `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`, but that isn't a C-style string. If you need C-style strings (e.g. for calling C code), you might want to think about exchanging `new char[...]` for `malloc` (C can call `free`, but it doesn't have access to `delete`)

Answer (score 4):

The other reviews have already covered the most important bits, so I'll just address a few things not already mentioned.

### Use your own function

If you have `strdup` available, the `operator""_cstr` can become a one-liner:

```
char * operator"" _cstr(unsigned long long int num) {
    return strdup(operator""_str(num).c_str());
}
```

If you don't have `strdup` (it's a standard POSIX, but not standard C++ function), one could easily create one or simply write the few lines of code to create the equivalent.  Alternatively, one could use the other operator as a base from which to construct a string, but I like this direction better.  In fact, I'd probably not provide a `cstr` operator at all because of the ugliness it introduces for memory management.

### Perform static checking

Instead of using `abi::__cxa_demangle()` which is, as you know, non-portable, we can do this:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(str), std::string>(), 
    "str does not match expected type 'std::string'\n");
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(cstr), char *>(), 
    "cstr does not match expected type 'char *'\n");
```

One could even go crazy and define an ugly macro for this:

```
#define TYPE_CHECK(str, tipo) \
   static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(str), tipo>(), \
       # str " does not match expected type '" # tipo "'\n")
```

Then use it as:

```
TYPE_CHECK(str, std::string);
TYPE_CHECK(cstr, const char *);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @indi [mentioned](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/198393/remaking-stdto-string-in-c-with-udls-user-defined-literals#comment382786_198393) you can use `(const char *)` parameter list. This allows `_cstr` to be `constexpr` and simplifies it:

```
constexpr const char * operator"" _cstr(const char * cstr) {
    return cstr;
}
```

`constexpr` here helps you to perform static checking:

```
constexpr bool cstring_equal(const char * lhs, const char * rhs) {
    return lhs[0] == rhs[0]
        && (lhs[0] == '\0' || cstring_equal(&lhs[1], &rhs[1]));
}

static_assert(cstring_equal(123_cstr, "123"), "123_cstr doesn't match expected value \"123\"");
```

Also `(const char *)` parameter list allows floating-point: `12.3_cstr`.